# How can a menu item in my activity get data from the tabs(view pager fragments)?

Tags: android, sqlite, android-viewpager, menuitem

I have an activity that has 4 tabs(view pager fragments). The fragments have forms in them, edittexts to record information. I would like to use a menu item in my activity to save the information to a database and to also create a pdf file. The file creates alright but no information is passed into it and it returns an I/O error. I believe the database has been created too but no information gets stored in it. I get a null.

```
public void save_final(){

    Serv_BaseDataFragment baseFragment = (Serv_BaseDataFragment)getSupportFragmentManager().findFragmentById(R.id.baseDataTab);
    baseFragment.serv_insertToBaseData_db();

    ServicingFragment serviceFragment = (ServicingFragment)getSupportFragmentManager().findFragmentById(R.id.servicingTab);
    serviceFragment.insertToServicing_db();

    ReplacementFragment replaceFragment = (ReplacementFragment)getSupportFragmentManager().findFragmentById(R.id.baseDataTab);
    replaceFragment.insertToReplacement_db();

    Toast.makeText(this, "ALL DATA STORED SUCCESSFULLY", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
    Intent intent = getIntent();
    finish();
    startActivity(intent);


}

public void writePdf(){
    String filename = Serv_BaseDataFragment.sysaid.getText().toString();

    Serv_CreatePDF fop = new Serv_CreatePDF();

    if (fop.writepdf(filename)) {
        Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), filename +  ".pdf created", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
    } else {
        Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "I/O error", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
    }
}


@Override
public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
    // Inflate the menu; this adds items to the action bar if it is present.
    getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.menu_maintenance, menu);
    return true;
}

@Override
public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
    // Handle action bar item clicks here. The action bar will
    // automatically handle clicks on the Home/Up button, so long
    // as you specify a parent activity in AndroidManifest.xml.
    int id = item.getItemId();

    //noinspection SimplifiableIfStatement
    if (id == R.id.action_settings) {
        Intent intent = new Intent(this, Serv_SettingsActivity.class);
        startActivity(intent);
        return true;
    }
    if (id == R.id.save_tickets) {
        save_final();
        writePdf();
        return true;
    }

    return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To fix my little problem, I moved the methods to insert data into the database from the fragments to the Activity. I created variables in the activity to reference the objects in the fragments.

Answer (score 0):

if they are both in the same activity and in the same fragment at the point you are getting the data, for example if we assume we have a menu item with id: chrome, a string name = "john" and a TextView mName it would be like:

```
     switch (item.getItemId()) {
       // case R.id.chrome:
        mName.setText(name);

    }
```

but one thing you have to know is that a fragment never has a context and there is nothing special about a fragment, just make sure when getting the data you are in the same fragment you ought to get the data from.

Comment: All four fragments are in the same activity. But the menu item is trying to get information from 3 fragments. The 4th fragment will just display a summary of the information after it has been stored in the database.

Comment: when you want to get info from fragment one make sure its fragment one thats being displayed on the screen at that particular point in time, then store the data in your activity, create `temporary` objects that will hold the data until you are ready to use them, stop viewing it from a complex angle, just get the data like you do when you have a single fragment

Comment: So can I get a sample code on how to get data from the fragment to the activity? The temporary objects have been created. I have decided to have the objects hold values when swiping the fragments